What happens to electronic structure of electrodes when we apply chemical potentials to them during NEGF calculations?
Assuming μL and μR are the chemical potential of left and right electrodes, and we are applying them to semiconductor electrodes. Assuming the chemical potential of one electrode is fixed,for example,μL is fixed,then where μL is located? Is it located at the fermi level? or is it randomly located in the gap? Or is it located in the conduction band?
And suggestions will be appreciated!

That is the problem of using semi-conductors in NEGF calculations.
There is no Fermi level of the semi-conductor. The Fermi-level can be defined anywhere between the valence and conduction bands. All placements are equal, from a single shot calculation point-of-view.
What an NEGF calculation does is simply to lift the entire electronic structure according to the chemical potential shift of the respective electrode.
So, if the Fermi-level of the left semi-conducting electrode is $E_F = \epsilon_{\mathrm{VB}} + (\epsilon_{\mathrm{CB}} - \epsilon_{\mathrm{VB}})/2$. Then for an applied bias all states gets shifted according to $\epsilon'_i \to \epsilon_i + \mu_L$, as well as the Fermi-level of the electrode $E'_F \to E_F + \mu_L$.
There is no shifting of the chemical potential with respect to the states, that is fixed in an NEGF simulation. If one were to change the chemical potential with respect to the states, that would correspond to adding/removing charge (depending on the sign).
Note that the above description only adheres to the electrode. The device is handled differently. And for what matters, it acts the same for a semi-conducting, or a metallic electrode.

Thank you, Sir, your answer made me realize that my question did not reflect my confusion. I have modified my question according to your answer. And I will post another question later.
